# what is the correct approach in order to host / integrate / show my existing MVC3 project inside orchard?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms, asp.net-mvc-areas

I've an existing MVC3 project that implements a certain functionality, this project has it's own views, and a separate Database.

now I'm required to use the same functionality inside one of my orchard project,so I thought that I can host this solution in somewhere and view it inside an iframe or something.

Am I thinking right?, 
is this the correct step to take in order to achieve this requirement inside Orchard?

to make it more clear, all I need to do is to view this solution and interact with it's controls and views from a hosting page inside orchard, and the subsequent requests should be handled by my solution in order to hit it's own data store and get back with the requested data in order to be displayed to the user.

any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

thanks for Bertrand Le Roy for his answer, I can now view my solution inside my
orchard website.
I came in to one more HUGE problem, which is that my application can no longer connect to my external database.

I've a DB that is hosted in some where else, and I'm using EntityFramework to deal with it.
the problem is that if I put the connection string inside my module web.config, or main orchard web.config, I run into several types of errors like:

**"*System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.*"**

or

**"System.Data.MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource."**

My question is: How could I pass my connectionstring correctly to my solution, assuming that I'm using Entity framework as my ORM.
Many thanks.

Comment: Would it be too much work to just write the current MVC3 project into Orchard? You can still access the separate database from it

Comment: If I can do just as what I've described in the question, I would not have to repeat myself again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to put it into a module.

You will have to move route definitions to a Routes.cs file (look at any existing such file for examples).

You will also need, in order to access your data store, to opt out of the ambient Orchard transaction around the data access code (`using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))`).

If you are using dependency injection, you may have some work to move that to the Autofac-based way of doing things in Orchard.

If you want your work to appear seamlessly in the Orchard admin, you may want to decorate your admin controllers with the Admin attribute. If you want your front-end to use the current theme, you'll have to add Themed attributes and maybe refactor your views so that they only emit HTML for the content zone instead of for the whole page.

Add a manifest (module.txt) to your module folder and you should be good to go.

Comment: I've already succeeded in showing my initial view (Step A) and it showed nicely inside orchard.

Comment: But I need to confirm that my postbacks will be handled by my controller. meaning that in step A, I ask the user to enter some data, then I should move him to view B, then C , and finally to a "ThankYou" step. will this be a straight forward steps like handling POST actions and that's it, or I should do more work in certain areas? thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm not really following what difficulties you are anticipating here. It really should be no different from regular MVC. Routing and model binding are the keys here and both work almost identically. The only difference is that because you need to avoid global code in a module-driven environment such as Orchard, the routes need to be declared and prioritized with a more distributed API (see any Routes.cs), but otherwise, it's the exact same thing.

Comment: EF doesn't force you to put the connection string into web.config, does it?

Comment: yes, and even if I provided the connectionstring directly to the Context Initialization code, it faild and reported back with "System.Data.MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource.".

when I tried committing the code that interacts with my DB, the calls worked fine, but I'm now unable to use my DB. kindly let me know if you have any thoughts, or working samples from other users.

Comment: That looks like a different question that should be asked to EF support people. I've never touched the thing myself, sorry. I think others have been able to make it work however.